# How to create a new python dictionary from loop results without overwrite

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I get stuck when I try to create a new dictionary with the result from each file.
Basically I have a bunch of files which I'm reading it using glob and json, so I managed to get the value from each file and it's working fine, it's displaying all files content with the different informations which is the expected and it's good.

But now I'm looking about how to create a new dictionary `new_dictonary = {} #in my code` using the variable I've got `get_hostname, get_fs_type, get_uptime` without overwrite the new dictionary, below is my code.

```
import json
import glob
    
test_inventory = glob.glob('inventory/facts_am4/*')
new_dictonary = {}
for files in test_inventory:
    with open(files, 'r') as jsonfile:
        myfile = json.load(jsonfile)
        get_hostname = myfile['ansible_facts']['facter_networking']['fqdn']
        get_fs_type = myfile['ansible_facts']['facter_filesystems']
        get_uptime = myfile['ansible_facts']['facter_system_uptime']['uptime']
        print('Hostname: ' + get_hostname)
        print('FS Type:' + get_fs_type)
        print('Uptime:' + get_uptime)
        #Here I need something which you grab the variables and create a new dictionary.
        #Without overwrite.
```

I really tried a lot of stuffs, I'm learning Python and I came here to kindly request you help.

Comment: Do you perhaps want a list of dictionaries, where each dict has the values from one of your files?

Comment: Yes, exactly! this is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

1. make a list of dictionaries, and add a new one to it for each file, or
2. make a nested dictionary, where each "info-dict" is keyed by the filename.

Using a list:

```
data_list = []
for filename in test_inventory:
    with open(filename, 'r') as file_obj:
        # read the data
        data = {'Hostname': get_hostname, 
                'FS Type': get_fs_type,
                'Uptime': get_uptime}
        data_list.append(data)
# Now data_list has a list of all your data, accessible as data_list[0], [1], etc..
```

Using a dictionary:

```
data_dict = {}
for filename in test_inventory:
    with open(filename, 'r') as file_obj:
        # as above
        data_dict[filename] = data
# Now data_dict has each file's data accessible as data_dict[filename]
```

Comment: Thank you very much @tzaman. 
This is exactly what I was looking for, worked here.